# Did Android Stop your thread when your device turn to sleep

Tags: android

I am using

```
HandlerThread bThread = (new  HandlerThread("backendHandler_thread",  
      Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
bThread.start();  
backendHandler = new Handler(bThread.getLooper());
```

then

```
backendHandler.postDelay(xxx, xxxx);
```

and found that this task don't run when the device turn to sleep and will come back to run after it wake up

I am testing on Samsung i9000 with original 2.1 Rom

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behavior.

If you need the device to stay awake you must use `WakeLock` via [`PowerManager.newWakeLock()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).

Beware that this will consume device's battery. It's preferable to use various Android API, so that when some change happens the system calls your code: like LocationManager for location changes or Alarm Manager for periodic wakeups.

What kind of tasks do you want to do in the background?

Comment: thx, so you mean no matter what PRIORITY I set to Thread it just will be pause when device turn to sleep? I am writing a app that need to make a http post to a sever every 55 second. base on you answer, I had to use AlarmManager to do this?

Comment: Of course you can use background thread with WakeLock, but then device's processor will be running and eating the battery. AlarmManager sounds like the best solution, the interval is a bit short. You'll have to investigate a bit. Also, if you need to check data on server, why not use server push: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html